# Using X3Dom MovieTexture on a sphere doesn't show whole movie

Tags: x3dom

I'm trying to use a movie as a texture on a sphere using X3Dom's `MovieTexture`. It is in equirectangular projection which would allow the user to look around (similar to Google StreetView).

The movie is mp4 or ogv and plays fine on e.g. a box shape from the [example code from the x3dom docs](http://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/basics/imagesMovies/).

However, on the sphere only 20 percent of the surface is covered with the movie texture while the rest is stretched over the surface.

[image: Sphere and Box shape with MovieTexture]

The relevant code looks like this:

```
<x3d width='500px' height='400px'>
  <scene>
    <shape>
      <appearance>
         <MovieTexture repeatS="false" repeatT="false" loop='true' url='bigBuckBunny.ogv'></MovieTexture>
      </appearance>
      <sphere></sphere>
    </shape>
  </scene>
</x3d>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is supposed to work but currently a [bug in x3dom](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/issues/629) when `repeatS="false"` is set on the texture.

The problem also occurs with a generic `<texture>` element that includes a `<canvas>` or `<video>` element.

The workaround that worked for me is to use a `<canvas>` with a `power-of-two` size to avoid setting `repeatS="false"`

An alternative would be to scale to original video.